# $_GET['character'] at php 5.2.17 doesn't dowk

Tags: php, get

I used this

```
<a href='download.php/download=true' >download link here</a>
```

so the url now is

```
example.com/download.php/download=true
```

I have this on my download.php

```
if(isset($_GET['download']))
```

I also tried this

```
if($_GET['download'] == 'true' )
```

those both $_GET doesn't worked... what I did is i tried to remove the IF CONDITION, and directly goes to it's (IF condition) content, and it works. That's why I conclude that the $_GET don't work here.

any help?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not submitting a query string in your URL. You need to change this:

```
<a href='download.php/download=true'>
```

To this:

```
<a href='download.php?download=true'>
                     ^
                     Note the changed character
```

Then you can use:

```
if( isset( $_GET['download'])) {
}
```